How to define a family of Hilbert $A-B$-bimodules $ \pi \ : \ M \to X $, parametrized by a $C^*$-algebra $X$?
Let $A$ and $B$ two $ C^* $ - algebras.
I would like to define a functor $ X \to \mathrm{Bimod}_{A,B} (X) $ which associate to any object $X$, the set of isomorphism classes of a family of Hilbert $A-B$-bimodules $ \pi \ : \ M \to X $, parametrized by the object $X$ expected to be a $C^*$-algebra, in order to try to define an asignement, $ \ f \to f^* \gamma $ which gives an isomorphism, $ \mathrm{Bimod}_{A,B} (X) \cong [X,C] $ by the map $ \overline{\phi} \ : \ \mathrm{Bimod}_{A,B} (X) \to [X,C] $ induced by the map $ \phi \ : \ \mathrm{Hom}_{C^{*}-\mathrm{Alg}} (X,C) \to \mathrm{Bimod}_{A,B} (X) $.
My question is, how is defined a family of Hilbert $A-B$-bimodules $ \pi \ : \ M \to X $, parametrized by the object $X$ which belongs to $ \mathrm{Bimod}_{A,B} (X) $ ? What is the nature of $X$ ? I hope it is a $C^*$-algebra as well.
Can you give me some references about this subject ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
